# J1 Visa - Do I need to file a US tax return?

Tags: usa, visa, j-visa

From April 29th to October 20th 2017 I was present in the USA under a J1 visa as a researcher. During this time I received a monthly salary in the form of a grant. Based on Article 22(2) from the Tax treaty between the US and the Netherlands (https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/nether.pdf) the entire amount is exempt from income tax and no taxes were withheld during my stay. I had no other source of income in the USA (including foreign).

Do I need to file for US taxes in this situation because form 1040NR-EZ mentions that there is an exception to file if:

"*2. You were a nonresident alien student, teacher, or trainee who was temporarily present in the United States under an “F,” “J,” “M,” or “Q” visa, and you have no income (such as wages, salaries, tips, etc., or scholarship or fellowship grants) that is subject to tax under section 871.*".

Thanks in advance.